# Tag duplicates with first occurrence ID

Tags: duplicates, stata

I'm using the `cluster`command and am having difficulties due to insufficient memory. To get around this problem I would like to delete all duplicate observations.

I would like to cluster via the variables A, B and C and I identify duplicate values as so:

```
   /* Create dummy data */
     input id A B C
        1 1 1 1
        2 1 1 1
        3 1 1 1
        4 2 2 2
        5 2 2 2
        6 2 2 2
        7 2 2 2 
        8 3 3 3
        9 3 3 3
        10 4 4 4
        end

sort A B C id

duplicates tag A B C, gen(dup_tag)
```

I would like to add a variable `dup_ID` which tells me that `id`s 2 and 3 are duplicates of `id` 1, `id`s 5 and 6 of `id` 4, and so on. How could I do this?

```
/* Desired result */

id A  B  C  dup_id
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  1
4  2  2  2  4
5  2  2  2  4
6  2  2  2  4
7  2  2  2  4
8  3  3  3  8
9  3  3  3  8
10 4  4  4  10
```

Comment: "Column" edited to "variable". We are not in spreadsheetland!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the first observation in each group of `A B C` using the subscript `[1]` on `ID`. Note the `(id)` argument in `bysort`, which sorts by `id`, but identifies the groups by `A`, `B`, and `C` only.

```
clear
input id A B C
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
3 1 1 1
4 2 2 2
5 2 2 2
6 2 2 2
7 2 2 2 
8 3 3 3
9 3 3 3
10 4 4 4
end

bysort A B C (id): gen dup_id = id[1]
li, noobs sepby(dup_id)
```

yielding

```
  +-------------------------+
  | id   A   B   C   dup_id |
  |-------------------------|
  |  1   1   1   1        1 |
  |  2   1   1   1        1 |
  |  3   1   1   1        1 |
  |-------------------------|
  |  4   2   2   2        4 |
  |  5   2   2   2        4 |
  |  6   2   2   2        4 |
  |  7   2   2   2        4 |
  |-------------------------|
  |  8   3   3   3        8 |
  |  9   3   3   3        8 |
  |-------------------------|
  | 10   4   4   4       10 |
  +-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

`duplicates` is a wonderful command (see its manual entry for why I say that), but you can do this directly:

```
bysort A B C : gen tag = _n == 1
```

tags the first occurrence of duplicates of `A B C` as 1 and all others as 0. For the other way round use `_n > 1`, `_n != 1`, or whatever.

EDIT:

So then the `id` of tagged observations is just

```
by A B C: gen dup_id = id[1]
```

For basic technique with `by:` see (e.g.) [this discussion](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004)

Comment: Very nice, however I would like returning for each group the id of the first occurence - so tag should be 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 10.

Comment: Quite; you did say that.